# Determine if a SharePoint 2010 Site Has Any Custom Solutions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am attempting to make a copy of a SharePoint 2010 web application and I can get it to the point where I have imported the content from the source site. At this point I hit the login page and that works fine but it then loads the "File not found" error along with a correlation id. Everything I have found on this error seems to point to there being some custom feature on the source site that I don't have on the copy. The question is . . . how can I determine if a SharePoint site has any custom features and what those may be?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Get-SPFeature and Get-SPSolution PowerShell cmd-lets.

```
Get-SPFeature –Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.Scope –eq "SITE"}
Get-SPSite http://somesite | Get-SPWeb –Limit ALL |%{ Get-SPFeature –Web $_ } | Select DisplayName,ID -Unique
```

Reference at [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607945.aspx)

Comment: Migeul . . . Thank you for the help. This combination of cmdlets is great. They showed me exactly what I needed. Unfortunately they also showed me that the list of features for both sites are exactly the same which means the problem lies elsewhere. I do truly appreciate the help. I will definitely be hanging on to this script.

Comment: Great! I recommend you have a look at the IIS logs on the server you are hitting and last but not least [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some file is not provisioned like master page, page layout, CSS etc. Check all the custom features/WSPs are being deployed.

If you're unsure about custom features, you may attempt to clean up the faulty feature with [SharePoint Feature Admin / Clean Up](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Falak . . . Thank you for the reply. I am thinking that I need to generate a list of all items that the source site has and compare it to the same list for the copy. I'm guessing that there is a way to do that using PowerShell but I am just beginning with this whole thing and am not fluent at all with it. I would love to create a script that will generate a list of all of the items that are included in a SharePoint site so I can compare two sites. Are there any good references, that you are aware of, that could help me in doing that?

Comment: You need to define the scope of troubleshooting. The issue you're facing is likely to be cause by a Master Page url error. Can you do check the site settings page by accessing _layouts/settings.aspx?